# Running echo command in docker container from python script doesn't work

Tags: python, bash, docker

I have the following code

```
import subprocess
import docker
import unittest

class DockerContainerHost(object):
    def execute(self, command):
        self._container.exec_run(command)

class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_twoHostsOneFile(self):
        with DockerContainerHost() as host1, DockerContainerHost() as host2:
            host1.execute('echo content > /tmp/foo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The thing is that everything works fine, but the `host1.execute('/bin/echo content > /tmp/foo')` line doesn't create the file `/tmp/foo`. When I tried to use `touch /tmp/foo` command it worked, but I need to create the file with content. How to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: As a bash command, it is valid, but I don't know if the line is parsed properly as I'm not familiar with the exact context here. You could try to pipe to tee?
`echo content | tee /tmp/foo`

Comment: Where do you expect the file to be created?

Comment: @KaffeMyers It doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: @TheFool I want the file to be created in container's /tmp directory

Comment: can you check in your host system? It may have been created there. At least if you were to run this via docker cli, this is what would happen. I am not familar with the docker python package. I tink its unlinkely but I would still check.

Comment: Where is bash being run from python? The `>` is parsed by a shell like `/bin/sh` or `bash`.

Comment: @BMitch, `self._container.exec_run(command)`. Its the docker python sdk doing an exec.

Comment: @TheFool `exec_run` launches a shell? The name suggests it is just doing a kernel exec.

Comment: @TheFool Yes, i have checked the host system and it is not created there. Also I have tried to use the ```touch /tmp/foo``` comand and it has created the file but basically with no contents.

Comment: You could try `sh -c "echo content > /tmp/file"` just to be sure to get no confusion with the redirect.

Comment: @BMitch, I don't know that package. I don't know what it's doing, precisely, when running an exec.

Comment: @BMitch, here are the docs for that https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.exec_run

Comment: @PawelBuchajczuk, also check the exit code of your exec command it returns a tuple of (exit_code, output).

Comment: ```host1.execute("/bin/bash -c 'echo content > /tmp/foo'")``` worked perfectly. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python and `docker exec` are not running a shell, and the redirect in `'echo content > /tmp/foo'` is expecting a shell to parse the `>`. You can specify running this with a shell using the following syntax:

```
'/bin/sh -c \'echo content > /tmp/foo\''
```

Note that this will parse the command inside the container, so the file will be created inside that container.